# ASP.Net MVC reset timer on layout during ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, timer

I have written a java script code at _layout.cshtml page to define a timer.

```
setTimeout("location.href='@Url.Action("Login", "Account", new { checkSessionID = 1 }) '", 7200000);
```

During post back timer get reset automatically that's fine. But I need to reset this timer during Jquery Ajax Call.

Can anyone suggest how to do this globally at one place for all ajax calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
var interval =  7200000;
function someFunction(){
}

var timeout = window.setTimeout(someFunction, interval);


$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(someFunction,interval);
});
```

Please note that this will not reset timer on another browser tabs.